# Redirect after logout depending on user symfony 2 with FOSUserBundle

Tags: security, symfony-2.1, fosuserbundle

After the users session expired (or logged out) I want to redirect him to a page depending on what the rights of the users have been.

I'm using Symfony 2.1.8-DEV and FOSUserBundle.

I think there has to be a event to attach a listener to, but I didn't found a approbiate listener, neither in symfonys core nor in FOSUserBundle.

Do you have any idea how to achieve this? Is it even possible?

Theoretically there must be a statement where the user gets logged out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this has nothing to do with fosuserbundle.  You need to register an event handler that listens for requests and check if session has expired.

**How to Register Event Listeners and Subscribers** http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html

This question was already asked here: [Catch session timeout Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846970/catch-session-timeout-symfony2)